# Formatting a radio button using asp.net Razor

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am creating a form and having trouble formatting the radio button, The radio buttons are aligned to centre and have a wide white background (my site wont be having a white background) is there anyway to get more control with razor to removed the background colour and to align the radiobuttons to the left?

here is the code that visual studio has produced for me:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <div>Yes: @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Smoke, "true", new { @checked = "checked" })</div>
    <div>No: @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Smoke, "false")</div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Smoke)
</div>
```

Comment: Set a css style to your radio buttons.

Comment: How do I add the style into the radio button razor code? I have tried adding css to the div tags but as I expected that had no effect.

Comment: div#myDiv INPUT{any style...}

Comment: no that didn't work, still shows the white background!

Comment: Solved it the following code sorted the issue  .editor-field input[type="radio"] {
    background:none;
}